# all element attributes in specific container selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, css-selectors

Lets say I have some HTML code that looks like this and I use CSS selectors to make a list of elements

```
<div class="item-cell">
    <div class="item-container">
        <div class ="item-price">
            <a href="www.xyz.com/xyz" class="item-img"> </a>
        <div class = "item-info">
            <span class = "price"> </span>
<div class="item-cell">
    <div class="item-container">
        <div class ="item-price">
            <a href="www.xyz.com/xyz" class="item-img"> </a>
        <div class = "item-info">
            <span class = "price"> </span>
```

`elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.item-cell div.item-container')`

now I have a list of elements that are at the item-container level. How would I go about finding the href value of each element in elements.

I was thinking I do something like

```
for element in elements:
    element.get_attribute("href")
```

I know I could explicitly go to the href level with the code but I want to check if each container contains href and if it does I want the value in that container. If I go specifically to the href level it will just skip the containers that do not have href in them.

Comment: I can't figure out from your description that what do you want to do with the containers without href?

Comment: well lets just say I want to print to a text "No Data Available"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("file://{PATH_TO_YOUR_FILE}")

elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.item-cell div.item-container')

for element in elements:
    try:
        link = element.find_element_by_tag_name('a')
        print(link.get_attribute('href'))
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print('No Data Available!')
    
driver.close()
```

Besides, I'd suggest surrounding your divs with `</div>` and add `https://` before your URLs.

```html
<div class="item-cell">
  <div class="item-container">
    <div class="item-price">
      <a href="https://www.example.com/xyz" class="item-img"> </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item-info">
      <span class="price"> </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item-cell">
  <div class="item-container">
    <div class="item-price">
      <a href="https://www.example.com/xyz" class="item-img"> </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item-info">
      <span class="price"> </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item-cell">
  <div class="item-container">
  </div>
</div>
```

If you don't add `https://` before your URLs, python will interpret it as a local URL if you run selenium in a local file.